# Disable deprecation in javascript console

Tags: javascript, node.js, deprecation-warning

I'm using a library from another person but it's probably pretty old and, even though it works just fine, I get a DEP066 deprecation error in my console when I run it.
I'm a COMPLETE noob when talking about javascript so I need your help. Is there a way to disable the deprecation warning/fix it if I use a newer function ?

EDIT:
Thank you so much! It works with the --no-deprecation option.

Comment: Yes, you can fix the library code by replacing the old function call with the new one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try running the the script using the the [**`--no-deprecation`**](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--no-deprecation) parameter which will "*silence deprecation warnings*":

```bash
node --no-deprecation script
```

Alternatively, [**`--no-warnings`**](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--no-warnings) will *"silence all process warnings (including deprecations)."*

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to hide the warnings..

```
const process= require('process');
process.removeAllListeners('warning');
```